# Use xcopy to determine new files

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, difference, xcopy

I can copy new files from source to destination with a batch file:

```
xcopy "D:\myFolder" "W:\projects\myFolder" /d /y /s
```

However, I'm interested in finding out what those files would be (without actually coping them) - sort of a this is what you would have copied text difference list. Is this possible in a batch file?

Comment: Add the `/L` option...

Comment: They thought of everything :) ! I didn't think there would be a switch for that!

Comment: If you think that's good check out `ROBOCOPY /?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the help page when typing `xcopy /?`:

> ```cmd
> Copies files and directory trees.
>
> XCOPY source [destination] [/A | /M] [/D[:date]] [/P] [/S [/E]] [/V] [/W]
>                            [/C] [/I] [/Q] [/F] [/L] [/G] [/H] [/R] [/T] [/U]
>                            [/K] [/N] [/O] [/X] [/Y] [/-Y] [/Z] [/B]
>                            [/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...]
> [...]
>   /F           Displays full source and destination file names while copying.
>   /L           Displays files that would be copied.
> [...]
> ```

There is a switch `/L` that does exactly what you are asking for: list all files that would be copied, but do not actually copy anything. You may combine this with the `/F` option in order to review source and destination.